# Is NTFS proprietary and what does that mean?

Tags: history, ntfs, licenses

Every source I can find says that NTFS is proprietary Microsoft code, but I can still find the [specifications](http://dubeyko.com/development/FileSystems/NTFS/ntfsdoc.pdf) for it and open source drivers, like NTFS-3G, made by Tuxera. I can't find any record of Microsoft releasing the specifications, working with Tuxera on NTFS, or trying to fight Tuxera either.

I am confused by this because it contradicts my understand of proprietary standards. Is NTFS-3G a violation of the license for NTFS? And if so, has Microsoft done anything about it?

Comment: TL;DR: the specs have been reverse-engineered, Microsoft has been less than happy about it, but copyright laws haven't been breached (for complicated legal reasons).  And the free drivers still have subtle bugs to this day.

Comment: "Yes", and "pure evil".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is better suited to a legal SX site.

Comment: @JeffSchaller A question for https://opensource.stackexchange.com/ maybe?